# How many connected components are there in $\text{Diff}^+(S^3 \times \mathbb R)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, fundamental-groups, diffeomorphism

I am reading an article about overtwisted contact structure and I am stuck at some point. I will not add all the context because it is quite long but I can summarize my question as follows:

I would like to know how many connected components are there in
$$\text{Diff}^+(S^3 \times \mathbb R),$$
the group of orientation preserving diffeomorphism of the $3$-sphere $S^3$ times $\mathbb R$. But I do not really see how to do that. I know that there is only one connected component in
$$\text{Diff}^+(S^3) \quad \text{and} \quad \text{Diff}^+(\mathbb R).$$
Indeed, it is obvious for $\mathbb R$ and for $S^3$ we know that there is an homotopy equivalence between
$$\text{Diff}(S^3) \to O(4)$$
where $O(4)$ is the orthogonal group of dimension 4, so that
$$\pi_0(O(4)) \cong \pi_0(\text{Diff}(S^3))$$
and therefore it has only two connected components (and only one preserves the orientation). But I do not see if there is any way to connect these two results to $\text{Diff}^+(S^3 \times \mathbb R)$. Do any of you have an idea how to do that ?

Comment: It looks to be disconnected. There are self-diffeomorphisms that preserve orientation but swap ends, so can't be homotopic to the identity map.